# How can I merge RDDs after repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions to generate final sorted RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a KV RDD of type `Array[Byte], Array[Byte]` on which I apply `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions`. So this will result in sorted partitions. When I do `.collect()` this will only fetch the data to the driver however I want to merge the partitions into a sorted RDD.

Can I use `zipPartitions` to zip RDDs in a sorted fashion? If so how?

Comment: I think I am missing something in the question but why not just use `sortBy` ? Do you need the intermediate partitions for something ?

Comment: Yes, I need intermediate partitions for some analysis, or else `sortBy` would have worked perfectly.